# Delete subgroup from HDF5 file in Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to delete a subgroup that I've wrote in a HDF5 file using h5py in Python. For example, according to the documentation, the subgroup called "MyDataset" can be deleted with:

```
del subgroup["MyDataset"]
```

I did it and effectively the subgroup is not longer accessible. However, the files does not reduce its size. My question, is it possible to recover the space from deleted subgroups using h5py without having to rewrite the remaining subgroups into a completely new file? Below I provide a small example that illustrate what I am saying:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

myfile = h5py.File('file1.hdf5')
data = np.random.rand(int(1e6))
myfile.create_dataset("MyDataSet", data=data)
myfile.close()
```

Then I open the file and remove the previous entry:

```
myfile = h5py.File('file1.hdf5')
del myfile["MyDataSet"]
```

and if you try to get the data using:

```
myfile["MyDataSet"].value
```

you will realize that the data is not longer accessible. However, if you check the size of the file it remains constant before and after calling to del.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`del myfile["MyDataSet"]` modifies the `File` object, but does not modify the underlying `file1.hdf5` file. The `file1.hdf5` file not modified until `myfile.close()` is called.

If you use a `with-statement`, `myfile.close()` will be called automatically for you when Python leaves the `with-statement`:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import os

path = 'file1.hdf5'
with h5py.File(path, "w") as myfile:
    data = np.random.rand(int(1e6))
    myfile.create_dataset("MyDataSet", data=data)
    print(os.path.getsize(path))

with h5py.File(path, "a") as myfile:
    del myfile["MyDataSet"]
    try:
        myfile["MyDataSet"].value
    except KeyError as err:
        # print(err)
        pass

print(os.path.getsize(path))
```

prints

```
8002144         <-- original file size
2144            <-- new file size
```

---

Notice that the first time, opening the `File` in write mode (`"w"`) creates a new file, the second time, opening the `File` in append mode (`"a"`, the default) allows reading the existant file and modifying it.

Comment: Oh. I see. I forgot to close the file. I am actually not very used to the use of "with", but I really like the way you do it. As long as I understand, the with will always force the call of the __exit__ method, which for h5py.File it seems to be the close()? Thank you very much for your nice example!

Comment: Yes that's right. The `__exit__` method calls `close()`. "Beginning with h5py 2.0, files must be manually closed, by calling the “close” method or by using the file object as a context manager." (from [What's new in h5py version 2.0](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.0.html)).